# Opening the Indicator in Multiple Charts

Tags: indicator, algorithmic-trading, metatrader4, mt4, metatrader5

I found an interesting MT4 indicator which shows remaining time of the next bar in the chart. But that works for the particular pairs which I would choose.

But I want that program to work/applied on all opened pairs by just applying to any of the opened one pair.

Please check the code below::::

```
//--- input parameters
input string LabelFont = "Arial";
input int LabelSize = 15;
input color LabelColor = clrRed;
input int LabelDistance = 15;
const string LabelName = "TimeToNextCandle";
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Custom indicator initialization function                         |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int OnInit()
  {
//---
   EventSetTimer(1);
   return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Custom indicator deinitialization function                       |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnDeinit(const int reason)
  {
//---
   EventKillTimer();
   ObjectDelete(0, LabelName);
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Custom indicator iteration function                              |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int OnCalculate(const int rates_total,
                const int prev_calculated,
                const datetime &time[],
                const double &open[],
                const double &high[],
                const double &low[],
                const double &close[],
                const long &tick_volume[],
                const long &volume[],
                const int &spread[])
  {
//---
   CalcTime();
//--- return value of prev_calculated for next call
   return(rates_total);
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Timer function                                                   |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnTimer()
  {
//---
   CalcTime();
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void CalcTime(void)
  {
   // checking is there output label. create it if necessary
   if (ObjectFind(LabelName) == -1)
   {
      ObjectCreate(0, LabelName, OBJ_LABEL, 0, 0, 0);
      ObjectSetString(0, LabelName, OBJPROP_FONT, LabelFont);
      ObjectSetInteger(0, LabelName, OBJPROP_FONTSIZE, LabelDistance);
      ObjectSetInteger(0, LabelName, OBJPROP_COLOR, LabelColor);
      ObjectSetInteger(0, LabelName, OBJPROP_ANCHOR, ANCHOR_RIGHT_LOWER);
      ObjectSetInteger(0, LabelName, OBJPROP_CORNER, CORNER_RIGHT_LOWER);
      ObjectSetInteger(0, LabelName, OBJPROP_XDISTANCE, LabelDistance);
      ObjectSetInteger(0, LabelName, OBJPROP_YDISTANCE, LabelDistance);
   }
   // calculating remaining time to next candle
   datetime TimeTo = PeriodSeconds() - (TimeCurrent() - Time[0]);
   // assembling the output string depending on current period on the chart
   string Out = StringFormat("%.2d", TimeSeconds(TimeTo));
   if (TimeTo >= 3600)
   {
      Out = StringFormat("%.2d:%s", TimeMinute(TimeTo), Out);
      if (TimeTo >= 86400)
        Out = StringFormat("%d day(s) %.2d:%s", int(TimeTo / 86400), TimeHour(TimeTo), Out);
      else
        Out = StringFormat("%d:%s", TimeHour(TimeTo), Out);
   }
   else
     Out = StringFormat("%d:%s", TimeMinute(TimeTo), Out);
   ObjectSetString(0, LabelName, OBJPROP_TEXT, StringFormat("%s (%.0f%s)", Out, 100.0 / PeriodSeconds() * TimeTo, "%"));
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

### <sup>Let's split the task into two parts:</sup>
Part I.:
How to measure the time.

Metatrader Terminal architecture has moved the code-execution units into three principal types:
- **`{0|1}`**-unique ExpertAdvisor-type of MQL4-code, per MT4.graph
- **`{0|1|..|n}`** CustomIndicatero-type of MQL4-code, per MT4.graph
- **`{0|1}`**-unique Script-type of MQL4-code, per MT4.graph

This may sound interesting to use more and more CustomIndicators, but there is a catch.

### Catch XXII.

All CustomIndicators and all ExpertAdvisors are responsively executed upon a Market Event message arrival. That means, whenever a Market Event arrives, all ExpertAdvisors and all CustomIndicators are pushed to execute their respective processing ( `OnTick(){...}` function is called in ExpertAdvisor(s), `OnCalculate(){...}` function is called in CustomIndicator ). That still sounds reasonable. The Catch XXII. is hidden in the fact, that all CustomIndicators **share a SINGLE THREAD.** Yes, **ALL !**

This translated into plain english means, avoid everything that could block from CustomIndicators and put it elsewhere, but the CustomIndicator MQL4-code.

Using *New*-**`MQL4.56789`** `EventSetTimer()`-facilities does not improve the already obvious problem, just the very opposite, so let's forget to use **`OnTimer()`**.

---

## So, how to safely design such feature?

The possible way is to use a low-profile service design, deployed in a helper-( non-trading )-MT4.graph for such utility service and best use a Script ( as it is absolutely under one's control, asynchronous to any Event-triggered EA / CI code-execution and **works safe and sound even during times, when the Market is closed or the connection to the MetaTrader Server is down** ).

This "central"-clock ( timing facility ) provides a unique, reference-time and stores it so as to be available to any "consumer" in other MT4.graphs.

```
// MQL4-Script
double assembleGV( int aTimeNOW,
                   int aPERIOD
                   ){

#define BrokerServerGMToffset 0                 // Yes, Real World isn't perfect :o)

       int aTimeToEoB = PeriodSeconds( aPERIOD ) - ( aTimeNOW - ( iTime( _Symbol, aPERIOD, 0 ) - BrokerServerGMToffset ) );
       return( aTimeToEoB + aTimeToEoB / PeriodSeconds( aPERIOD ) );                                // INT + FRAC ( non-%, but having the value of the remainder )
}

while True{
      Sleep( 250 ); int TimeNow = TimeGMT();
   // -------------------------------------- COOL DOWN CPU-CORE(s)
      GlobalVariableSet( "msMOD_TimeSERVICE_4_PERIOD=60",       assembleGV( TimeNow, PERIOD_M1  ) ); // for PERIOD_M1
      GlobalVariableSet( "msMOD_TimeSERVICE_4_PERIOD=300",      assembleGV( TimeNow, PERIOD_M5  ) ); // for PERIOD_M5 
      GlobalVariableSet( "msMOD_TimeSERVICE_4_PERIOD=900",      assembleGV( TimeNow, PERIOD_M15 ) ); // for PERIOD_M15
      GlobalVariableSet( "msMOD_TimeSERVICE_4_PERIOD=1800",     assembleGV( TimeNow, PERIOD_M30 ) ); // for PERIOD_M30
      GlobalVariableSet( "msMOD_TimeSERVICE_4_PERIOD=3600",     assembleGV( TimeNow, PERIOD_H1  ) ); // for PERIOD_H1 
      GlobalVariableSet( "msMOD_TimeSERVICE_4_PERIOD=14400",    assembleGV( TimeNow, PERIOD_H4  ) ); // for PERIOD_H4 
      GlobalVariableSet( "msMOD_TimeSERVICE_4_PERIOD=86400",    assembleGV( TimeNow, PERIOD_D1  ) ); // for PERIOD_D1 
      GlobalVariableSet( "msMOD_TimeSERVICE_4_PERIOD=604800",   assembleGV( TimeNow, PERIOD_W1  ) ); // for PERIOD_W1 
      GlobalVariableSet( "msMOD_TimeSERVICE_4_PERIOD=2592000",  assembleGV( TimeNow, PERIOD_MN1 ) ); // for PERIOD_MN1

      GlobalVariableSet( "msMOD_TimeSERVICE_4_PERIOD=120",      assembleGV( TimeNow, PERIOD_M2  ) ); // for PERIOD_M2 
      GlobalVariableSet( "msMOD_TimeSERVICE_4_PERIOD=180",      assembleGV( TimeNow, PERIOD_M3  ) ); // for PERIOD_M3 
      GlobalVariableSet( "msMOD_TimeSERVICE_4_PERIOD=240",      assembleGV( TimeNow, PERIOD_M4  ) ); // for PERIOD_M4 
      GlobalVariableSet( "msMOD_TimeSERVICE_4_PERIOD=360",      assembleGV( TimeNow, PERIOD_M6  ) ); // for PERIOD_M6 
      GlobalVariableSet( "msMOD_TimeSERVICE_4_PERIOD=600",      assembleGV( TimeNow, PERIOD_M10 ) ); // for PERIOD_M10
      GlobalVariableSet( "msMOD_TimeSERVICE_4_PERIOD=720",      assembleGV( TimeNow, PERIOD_M12 ) ); // for PERIOD_M12
      GlobalVariableSet( "msMOD_TimeSERVICE_4_PERIOD=1200",     assembleGV( TimeNow, PERIOD_M20 ) ); // for PERIOD_M20
      GlobalVariableSet( "msMOD_TimeSERVICE_4_PERIOD=7200",     assembleGV( TimeNow, PERIOD_H2  ) ); // for PERIOD_H2 
      GlobalVariableSet( "msMOD_TimeSERVICE_4_PERIOD=10800",    assembleGV( TimeNow, PERIOD_H3  ) ); // for PERIOD_H3 
      GlobalVariableSet( "msMOD_TimeSERVICE_4_PERIOD=21600",    assembleGV( TimeNow, PERIOD_H6  ) ); // for PERIOD_H6 
      GlobalVariableSet( "msMOD_TimeSERVICE_4_PERIOD=28800",    assembleGV( TimeNow, PERIOD_H8  ) ); // for PERIOD_H8 
      GlobalVariableSet( "msMOD_TimeSERVICE_4_PERIOD=43200",    assembleGV( TimeNow, PERIOD_H12 ) ); // for PERIOD_H12
}
```

---

### Part II.:
How to display the time in all MT4.graphs
in a most lightweight form?

Given the central service takes care of respective **`ENUM_TIMEFRAMES`** listed ( being "visited" or not by other MT4.graphs ) and posting the pre-fabbed results of such "time-service" calculus, 
any potential "consumer"
may just asynchronously check and react to the "time-service" posted values,
in places, where feasible and safe in it's respective flow of code-execution, kind users are under full control to declare, where such lightweight GUI-call may appear and where all updates may benefit from ( a potentially deferred ) enforced GUI-repaint:

```
/* MQL4-ExpertAdvisor
      or
        other Script
      or even
        a lightweight add-on to a CustomIndicator */

#define LabelNAME          "msMOD_StackOverflowDEMO"

bool    aDeferred_GUI_REPAINT = False;
.
..
RepaintTIME();
..
.
if (  aDeferred_GUI_REPAINT ){
      aDeferred_GUI_REPAINT = False;
      WindowRedraw();
}

void RepaintTIME(){
     static string aGlobalVariableNAME = "msMODmsMOD_TimeSERVICE_4_PERIOD=" + (string)PeriodSeconds();

     ObjectSetString( 0,
                      LabelNAME,            // external responsibility to set/create
                      OBJPROP_TEXT,
                      StringFormat( "%d (%.0f %%)",
                                     int( GlobalVariableGet( aGlobalVariableNAME ) ),                       // SECONDS TILL EoB
                                     (    GlobalVariableGet( aGlobalVariableNAME ) % 1 ) * 100.0 )          // PER CENTO [%] EXPRESSED REMAINDER
                      );
     aDeferred_GUI_REPAINT = True;
}
```

[image]